# How to show fusion table rows that ST_INTERSECTS multiple possible locations in a single layer?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a pretty routine fusion table that contains rows of data where each row has a location column that contains a polygon (or multiple polygons in a multigeometry). I use this fusion table data to draw polygons on a google map object within a web page using `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer`. Creating a query that uses a single location as a `CIRCLE` with a small radius within an `ST_INTERSECTS` is a trivial exercise and works perfectly.

However, I now need to be able to query all rows within the fusion table that intersect multiple possible locations (essentially the results of a geocode of a search term). Each row need only intersect at least one of the locations to be included in the result set.

Things I have already tried and or considered ...

1) Multiple layers don't work as I would be limited to at most 5 locations and only one of them can be styled the way I need.

2) Building a `LatLngBounds` with each location then doing an `ST_INTERSECTS` on the `RECTANGLE` formed by the bounds. As is obvious once you do it, this shows you all polygons that are between two distant locations, but don't actual contain the locations (because we're now looking for polygons intersecting a large rectangle around the two points) - something I don't want.

3) You can't do `"ST_INTERSECTS(GEOMETRY, CIRCLE(location1, 1)) OR ST_INTERSECTS(GEOMETRY, CIRCLE(location2, 1))" <=` This would be the perfect solution if it worked!

4) You can't do an SQL union with a fusion table query.

5) You can't do multiple SQL selects within a single fusion table query.

Is there any way I can do this within a single fusion table layer?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only possible solution here may be to request first the rows(a unique column with an ID, but not the internally stored `rowId` ), single requests for each location.

When you got all the results, build the query for the FTlayer based on the returned ID's , a'la:

```
where: "columnWithIds IN('collected','ids','from','the','previous','requests')"
```

If this will be applicable in your situation will depend on

1. the number of locations(limits for webService-requests)
2. the number of returned rows(browserLimit for URL-length)

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle. Unfortunately I can't do that. I can't do direct SQL queries because I don't want to go through OAUTH authentication from the Javascript. I was hoping to be able to hand a complex spatial query straight to the FusionTableLayer. It's moot now anyway as the customer has changed the way they want data displayed. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Is the access set to private?

Comment: Yes, it is. The client has now changed how they want to display the data and this is now a moot point. Thank you for your help, regardless.